# Shortcut to navigate back to the Android Studio code editor

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I use cmd +  to navigate to the different sections in Android Studio.  How do I use keyboard shortcut to navigate back to the code editor?

Comment: try the keyboard `alt + 1`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Doesn't work.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same question, ESC works in some places, but for example it doesn't work in the Terminal, were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried it on Windows, but on a Mac you can just press `Esc` to navigate back to the editor from a window.

Comment: Works for me on Windows!

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Ctrl+Home

you can also see all shortcuts from android studio File->Settings then

Keymap -> Main menu -> Navigate -> Related Symbol

and if you want you can assign you own keyborad or even mouse (or booth) shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl + e
```

Will walk you through the recent files

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to go to recent files, just want the cursor to go to the editor.